# Anchor tags working inconsistently in my web page

Tags: html, anchor, href

Here's an actual video recording of what the problem is (I'm not trying to advertise in any way): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b38cQ0VGWI

So I'm creating a website just for practice's sake, and everything was going smoothly until I ran into this problem. I have 2 `<nav>` menus, where the top main nav bar leads one to **another page**, while the 2nd nav bar leads one to a certain section within the **same page**. But I'm having problems with the 2nd nav bar. So below is the html I'm using:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#drama">Drama</a></li>
                <li><a href="#comedy">Comedy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#romance">Romance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#action">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

After this is a series of movie picture lists but I'm only going input 2 below as an example:

```
<div class="grid-picture">
    <!--First row of movies-->
        <div id="action">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91atCmxi6hL._UR1200,1600_RI_.jpg">
                    <h3>John Wick</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Triller</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
<br>
        <!--1st row of romance movies-->
        <div id="romance">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
                    <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, "John Wick" is within a div tag with an ID of "action", while "Love, Rosie" is within a div tag with an ID of "romance." Now, the "Action" link works fine; it directs the page exactly where the movies within the ID of "action" are. However, when I click the "Romance" link, it doesn't take me to the bottom of the website. Rather, it takes me to the same place as if I clicked the "Action" link.

So basically, the anchor tag isn't working for me even though I made sure to input **href="#romance"** and also made sure to wrap around the movie "Love, Rosie" within a div tag with an ID of "romance". External links work just fine, only that internal links aren't working as I assumed it would. I also quadruple checked if I had any unclosed div tags, but that wasn't the case.

PS: all of the movies are in the same page.

Comment: Is romance at the bottom of your page ? Maybe the bottom of the page is reached and the browser cannot scroll downer

Comment: well yes but not at the very bottom. Cause I have like 3-4 rows of movies below the movies with the id of "romance."

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question ? Just to show the behavior when you try to reached romance

Comment: Is the content long enough? The browser can't scroll if there is no place to scroll. Also: Block elements (like `p`, `h1-h6`) aren't allowed inside inline elements (like `a`, `span`)

Comment: @RomainV I wish I could but StackOverflow is preventing me from doing it since I'm a new member );

Comment: @AlexG yes the content is definitely long enough. I have 4 picture items in one row, and have a total of 10+ columns of that. Also I adjusted the image size in CSS so that each image will have a height of 500px. I didn't use any block elements inside the anchor tag as far as I know.

Comment: @RomainV actually I just recorded my screen and uploaded it on youtube. Can you check it out? the link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b38cQ0VGWI

Comment: @AlexG — `<a>` isn't an inline element any more.

Comment: Thanks good stuff. Ok so I don't know if it's just a bad copy and paste in stack overflow, but you missing a </div> to close your .grid-picture

Comment: @Quentin It is still an inline element, but "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within". So in OPs code there is no mistake in that part.

Comment: @RomainV ah yea it was a bad copy & paste lol. I forgot to say it but I do have a </div> closing tag in the actual coding, just that I didn't paste it above but will fix it

Comment: @JosephKim You don't use multiple ids of "romance" by any chance? actions seems to work fine in the clip you posted.

Comment: @AlexG yea I don't use multiple IDs of "romance." I just wrap everything I want in the romance genre within a <div id="romance> just once, with a closing tag once I list all the romance movies I want. Am I supposed to have multiple ids?

Comment: @JosephKim Nono, thats correct as is. Just wanting to be sure, as IDs are only allowed once per site.

Comment: @AlexG — "inline" isn't even a categorisation of element used by HTML any more. It went out with HTML 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchor tag goes to the wrong section of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206542/anchor-tag-goes-to-the-wrong-section-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Your next question appears to be a copy+paste duplicate. Since that one has an answer, I will mark this one as the duplicate (even though technically the other one is).