# Anchor tag goes to the wrong section of a web page

Tags: html, css, anchor, href

Here's an actual video recording of what the problem is (I'm not trying to advertise in any way): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b38cQ0VGWI

So I'm creating a website just for practice's sake, and everything was going smoothly until I ran into this problem. I have 2 `<nav>` menus, where the top main nav bar leads one to **another page**, while the 2nd nav bar leads one to a certain section within the **same page**. But I'm having problems with the 2nd nav bar. So below is the html I'm using:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#drama">Drama</a></li>
                <li><a href="#comedy">Comedy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#romance">Romance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#action">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

After this is a series of movie picture lists but I'm only going input 2 below as an example:

```
<div class="grid-picture">
    <!--First row of movies-->
        <div id="action">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91atCmxi6hL._UR1200,1600_RI_.jpg">
                    <h3>John Wick</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Triller</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
<br>
        <!--1st row of romance movies-->
        <div id="romance">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
                    <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, "John Wick" is within a div tag with an ID of "action", while "Love, Rosie" is within a div tag with an ID of "romance." Now, the "Action" link works fine; it directs the page exactly where the movies within the ID of "action" are. However, when I click the "Romance" link, it doesn't take me to the bottom of the website. Rather, it takes me to the same place as if I clicked the "Action" link.

So basically, the anchor tag isn't working for me even though I made sure to input `href="#romance"` and also made sure to wrap around the movie "Love, Rosie" within a div tag with an ID of "romance". External links work just fine, only that internal links aren't working as I assumed it would. I also quadruple checked if I had any unclosed div tags, but that wasn't the case.

All of the movies are in the same page.

Below is the CSS (sorry for the disorganization, still working on that):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    color: #E52EAE;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

.navbar {
    margin-right: 227px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #22D8E5;
}

.navbar a:visited {
    color: #22D8E5;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: red;
}

#showcase {
    background-image:url('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/c/4/8/1367231-beautiful-black-cool-background-1920x1200-for-windows-7.jpg');
    background-position: center right;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 850px;
    background-position: left;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.movies {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
}

.movies img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: coral;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

And here's the whole html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Video Library</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="movies.css">
</head>
<body>

<section id="showcase">
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LaughTime</a></li>
                <li><a href="movies.index.html">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="practice3.index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Movie List</h1>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#drama">Drama</a></li>
                <li><a href="#comedy">Comedy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#romance">Romance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#action">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
        </div>
</section>


<div class="grid-picture">
    <!--First row of movies-->
        <div id="action">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91atCmxi6hL._UR1200,1600_RI_.jpg" alt="john wick">
                    <h3>John Wick</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Triller</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/kingsman-the-secret-service-final-poster.jpg">
                    <h3>Kingsmen</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2381249/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81wcVvqV8pL._RI_.jpg">
                    <h3>Mission Impossible: Rogue Nation</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Thriller</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91KkWf50SoL._SL1500_.jpg">
                    <h3>The Dark Knight</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
                </a>
            </div>

        <br>
        <!--2nd row of movies-->
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://pics.filmaffinity.com/Deadpool-834516798-large.jpg">
                    <h3>Deadpool</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/xmenmovies/images/2/22/Logan-Poster-5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131012906">
                    <h3>Logan</h3>
                        <p>Action, Drama, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6806448/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://musicart.xboxlive.com/7/e9225100-0000-0000-0000-000000000002/504/image.jpg?w=1920&h=1080">
                    <h3>Fast & Furious: Hobbs & Shaw</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/iron-man-1-poster.jpg">
                    <h3>Iron Man</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>


        <br>
        <!--3rd row of movies-->
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMyNDkzMzI1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODcxODg5MjI@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Thor: Ragnarok</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631867/" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://collider.com/wp-content/uploads/edge-of-tomorrow-poster3.jpg">
                    <h3>Edge of Tomorrow</h3>
                        <p>Action, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024469/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTI3NzcxMjkzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDY0NTQ0MDE@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Non-Stop</h3>
                        <p>Action, Thriller, Mystery</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91gANPtj-7L._SL1500_.jpg">
                    <h3>Taken</h3>
                        <p>Action, Thriller</p>
                </a>
            </div>


        <br>
        <!--4th row of movies-->
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMxNjY2MDU1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzY1MTUwNTM@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Avengers: Infinity War</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDE2ODcwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzI2NzQ2NzM@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Avengers: Endgame</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Drama</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6146586/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/03/a1/1b03a1a68c4616f8fb203d00a2849a9a.jpg">
                    <h3>John Wick 3: Chapter 3 - Parabellum</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Thriller</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270797/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91ZwG8Ytb3L._RI_.jpg">
                    <h3>Venom</h3>
                        <p>Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller</p>
                </a>
            </div>


        <br>
        <!--5th row of movies-->
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwMjU5OTgxNjZeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDUxNDYxODEx._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Guardians of the Galaxy</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_6">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ0MTgyNjAxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjUzMDkyODE@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Captain America: Civil War</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_7">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71moJUZkLwL._SL1285_.jpg">
                    <h3>Spiderman</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4912910/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mission-impossible-fallout-poster-tom-cruise.jpg">
                    <h3>Mission Impossible: Fallout</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Thriller</p>
                </a>
            </div>


        <br>
        <!--6th row of movies-->
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790864/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91mPBc21TcL._RI_.jpg">
                    <h3>The Maze Runner</h3>
                        <p>Action, Mystery, Sci-Fi</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5095030/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1CGAvzql5L._SL1500_.jpg">
                    <h3>Ant-Man and the Wasp</h3>
                        <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2082221/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="http://mblogthumb1.phinf.naver.net/MjAxODAxMTNfMjk2/MDAxNTE1NzcyNTg1MTc0.NeCkyOl-gJwl4ksYNeAmYSHCHg9iRVLpCh0Qy4zFR1Ag.MfdAtUo9Efw0rx_8zKgkzAAj1azlUfm-ov3qgDuLRbUg.JPEG.zzid2/movie_image.jpg?type=w800">
                    <h3>범죄와의 전</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2625030/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_6">
                <img src="http://mblogthumb4.phinf.naver.net/20130506_151/refine9_136781657095534Gd5_JPEG/movie_image.jpg?type=w2">
                    <h3>신세계</h3>
                        <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <br>
        <!--1st row of romance movies-->
        <div id="romance">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
                    <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2194499/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA1ODUzMDA3NzFeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDgxMTYxNTk@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>About Time</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1041829/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGM5YTNiYzktNmEwZC00ZjE5LWIyNzEtOTUwNDE0NmVkYzE3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>The Proposal</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Drama, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1129423/">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGZhYzFjY2ItNDVmZi00Y2Q1LWFmMDgtMzAwYTU3NTI3ZGU4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxMTY0OTQ@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Fireproof</h3>
                        <p>Drama, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <!--1st row of comedy movies-->
        <div id="comedy">
            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
                    <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2194499/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA1ODUzMDA3NzFeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDgxMTYxNTk@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>About Time</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1041829/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGM5YTNiYzktNmEwZC00ZjE5LWIyNzEtOTUwNDE0NmVkYzE3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>The Proposal</h3>
                        <p>Comedy, Drama, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="movies">
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1129423/">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGZhYzFjY2ItNDVmZi00Y2Q1LWFmMDgtMzAwYTU3NTI3ZGU4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxMTY0OTQ@._V1_.jpg">
                    <h3>Fireproof</h3>
                        <p>Drama, Romance</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>




</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks to be okay, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcz71yro/) - maybe supply all of your HTML, it's more than likely you have a section of invalid code that is preventing this action. Alternatively, use this [HTML Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and see if you can find the issue yourself!

Comment: As @EGC stated, please provide more code. I tested the code above and it works as expected, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Ivan86 Does that mean there's a problem with my CSS? I'll edit my post above and paste my css there

Comment: @JosephKim It would be best if you could post a minimal working example here or in JSFiddle or similar so we can test it and tell you where the problem is. I tested this code and it does what you would want it to. Check it out here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gstbkf3)

Comment: Nice, thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: @JosephKim Did the solution I wrote below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example of the code you provided. The changes are:

- added `position:relative;` to `.movies` CSS class
- added `.grid-picture { position:relative; float:left; }` to the CSS
- added `<br style="clear:both;"/>` right before each movie category closing `</div>` tag in order to make sure that the div resizes to match the height of its content (old trick)

Note: I also tidied up your code a bit. You can run the example below to test it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  color: #E52EAE;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.navbar {
  margin-right: 227px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #22D8E5;
}

.navbar a:visited {
  color: #22D8E5;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: red;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/c/4/8/1367231-beautiful-black-cool-background-1920x1200-for-windows-7.jpg');
  background-position: center right;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 850px;
  background-position: left;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.movies {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1px;
}

.movies img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: coral;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.grid-picture {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Video Library</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="movies.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="showcase">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LaughTime</a></li>
          <li><a href="movies.index.html">Movies</a></li>
          <li><a href="practice3.index.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Movie List</h1>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#drama">Drama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comedy">Comedy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#romance">Romance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#action">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>


  <div class="grid-picture">
    <!--First row of movies-->
    <div id="action">
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91atCmxi6hL._UR1200,1600_RI_.jpg" alt="john wick">
          <h3>John Wick</h3>
          <p>Action, Crime, Triller</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/kingsman-the-secret-service-final-poster.jpg">
          <h3>Kingsmen</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2381249/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81wcVvqV8pL._RI_.jpg">
          <h3>Mission Impossible: Rogue Nation</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Thriller</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91KkWf50SoL._SL1500_.jpg">
          <h3>The Dark Knight</h3>
          <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <br>
      <!--2nd row of movies-->
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://pics.filmaffinity.com/Deadpool-834516798-large.jpg">
          <h3>Deadpool</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/xmenmovies/images/2/22/Logan-Poster-5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131012906">
          <h3>Logan</h3>
          <p>Action, Drama, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6806448/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://musicart.xboxlive.com/7/e9225100-0000-0000-0000-000000000002/504/image.jpg?w=1920&h=1080">
          <h3>Fast & Furious: Hobbs & Shaw</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/iron-man-1-poster.jpg">
          <h3>Iron Man</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <br>
      <!--3rd row of movies-->
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMyNDkzMzI1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODcxODg5MjI@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Thor: Ragnarok</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631867/" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://collider.com/wp-content/uploads/edge-of-tomorrow-poster3.jpg">
          <h3>Edge of Tomorrow</h3>
          <p>Action, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024469/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTI3NzcxMjkzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDY0NTQ0MDE@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Non-Stop</h3>
          <p>Action, Thriller, Mystery</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91gANPtj-7L._SL1500_.jpg">
          <h3>Taken</h3>
          <p>Action, Thriller</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <br>
      <!--4th row of movies-->
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMxNjY2MDU1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzY1MTUwNTM@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Avengers: Infinity War</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDE2ODcwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzI2NzQ2NzM@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Avengers: Endgame</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Drama</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6146586/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/03/a1/1b03a1a68c4616f8fb203d00a2849a9a.jpg">
          <h3>John Wick 3: Chapter 3 - Parabellum</h3>
          <p>Action, Crime, Thriller</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270797/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91ZwG8Ytb3L._RI_.jpg">
          <h3>Venom</h3>
          <p>Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <br>
      <!--5th row of movies-->
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwMjU5OTgxNjZeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDUxNDYxODEx._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Guardians of the Galaxy</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_6">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ0MTgyNjAxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjUzMDkyODE@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Captain America: Civil War</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_7">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71moJUZkLwL._SL1285_.jpg">
          <h3>Spiderman</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4912910/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mission-impossible-fallout-poster-tom-cruise.jpg">
          <h3>Mission Impossible: Fallout</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Thriller</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <br>
      <!--6th row of movies-->
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790864/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91mPBc21TcL._RI_.jpg">
          <h3>The Maze Runner</h3>
          <p>Action, Mystery, Sci-Fi</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5095030/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1CGAvzql5L._SL1500_.jpg">
          <h3>Ant-Man and the Wasp</h3>
          <p>Action, Adventure, Comedy</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2082221/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="http://mblogthumb1.phinf.naver.net/MjAxODAxMTNfMjk2/MDAxNTE1NzcyNTg1MTc0.NeCkyOl-gJwl4ksYNeAmYSHCHg9iRVLpCh0Qy4zFR1Ag.MfdAtUo9Efw0rx_8zKgkzAAj1azlUfm-ov3qgDuLRbUg.JPEG.zzid2/movie_image.jpg?type=w800">
          <h3>범죄와의 전</h3>
          <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2625030/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_6">
          <img src="http://mblogthumb4.phinf.naver.net/20130506_151/refine9_136781657095534Gd5_JPEG/movie_image.jpg?type=w2">
          <h3>신세계</h3>
          <p>Action, Crime, Drama</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div>


    <br>
    <!--1st row of romance movies-->
    <div id="romance">
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
          <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2194499/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA1ODUzMDA3NzFeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDgxMTYxNTk@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>About Time</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1041829/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGM5YTNiYzktNmEwZC00ZjE5LWIyNzEtOTUwNDE0NmVkYzE3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>The Proposal</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Drama, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1129423/">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGZhYzFjY2ItNDVmZi00Y2Q1LWFmMDgtMzAwYTU3NTI3ZGU4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxMTY0OTQ@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Fireproof</h3>
          <p>Drama, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <!--1st row of comedy movies-->
    <div id="comedy">
      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638002/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://kbimages1-a.akamaihd.net/beb95aaa-36b7-444d-8557-0cb7efa8e898/1200/1200/False/love-rosie-1.jpg">
          <h3>Love, Rosie</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2194499/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA1ODUzMDA3NzFeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDgxMTYxNTk@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>About Time</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1041829/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGM5YTNiYzktNmEwZC00ZjE5LWIyNzEtOTUwNDE0NmVkYzE3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>The Proposal</h3>
          <p>Comedy, Drama, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movies">
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1129423/">
          <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGZhYzFjY2ItNDVmZi00Y2Q1LWFmMDgtMzAwYTU3NTI3ZGU4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxMTY0OTQ@._V1_.jpg">
          <h3>Fireproof</h3>
          <p>Drama, Romance</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Omg...you are a genius! Lifesaver even lol. Spent over 30+hrs trying to figure out what was wrong, and never really got a concrete answer even after asking online. Tbh I'm still a bit confused as of to why those "codes" you added were necessary in order for the anchor link to work properly, but either way I'll make sure to study it hard. Again, thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: @JosephKim Your welcome. Glad it worked for you. Adding `position: relative;` and `float:left;` helps position the element within its parent. The `<br style="clear: both;" />` is an old trick to force the parent element to take the height of its tallest child. But the instruction has to be the last line of code before the closing parent's `</div>` tag in order for it to work. This can also be solved by adding some more CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

A link to an anchor only scrolls the page, so if you set a link to an anchor at the bottom of the page the site cannot scroll further than until it reaches the end of its content.
This could be your issue here. You can easily test this if you set the height of the
`.grid-picture` container to a huge value to make the page scroll beyound the height of the actual content.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for this `gallery filter`

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- MAIN (Center website) -->
<div class="main">

<h1>MYLOGO.COM</h1>
<hr>

<h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('nature')"> Nature</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('people')"> People</button>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Mountains</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Lights</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Forest</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/cars1.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Retro</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/cars2.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Fast</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/cars3.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Classic</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/people1.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Girl</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/people2.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Man</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/people3.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Woman</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- END GRID -->
</div>

<!-- END MAIN -->
</div>
```